# Socket IO - appending messages to the correct location

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am creating a real time chat application, where users can chat with other users in real time. All users are stored in my MongoDB Database. I'm using React on the frontend, and node with express on the backend.

When users connect to the socket server, they're added to the users array stored on the server, like so:

```
var users = [
   // User objects
   {username: test1, id: 32d2, socketId: ue3e9393kd3},
   {username: test2, id: 322, socketId: ude3e339393kd3},
   {username: test3, id: 333dw2, socketId: ud33e9393kd3},
]
```

On the frontend, when chatting with a user, they first select the other users  name from a messages list, and it redirects to the route `chat/otheruserid`. So whatever user they want to chat with, the other users id would be stored in the url.

When submitting the message to send, it is received by the server and sent  back to the client. I currently use the following code to send message  events.

```
io.to(user.socketId).emit('send message', msg)
```

This socket id would be obtained by filtering the users array to find a specific user (i.e the one they selected on the frontend to chat with)

The problem I have, is if using the example above, if the user **test1** had a chat with **test2**, and a chat with **test3**, if both **test2** and **test3** sent a message to user **test1**, how would I be able to append the message to the DOM of the correct chat screen.

For example, if **test2** and **test3** send messages to **test1** at approximately the same time, and **test1** was on the chat page with **test2**, then you could append the message from **test2** to the current page's DOM. However if when on the chat page with **test2**, and **test3** sends a message, how would I append the message from **test3** to the chat screen located at the path: `chat/test3id`, so when the user eventually goes to this path, the new message has been appended to the dom? Thanks.

Comment: I assume you're storing the whole chat history in your database somewhere, right?  So, you record the fact that message "Hello to you" was sent from test1 to test3 at such-and-such a time.  When that happens, you can send a trigger out to the test3 socket, if it is still connect, to tell the app to refresh itself.  At that point, you can send all messages for test3.

Answer (score 0):

@Sam I think, you need a way to associate the incoming msgs with the correct chat screen on the frontend. One good approach is to use target user's id when sending msg from the server to the client.

I can show you a simplified example.

- server side

```
// Assuming user is the sender and targetUserId is the id of the user they are chatting with
io.to(targetUserSocketId).emit('send message', { senderId: user.id, message: msg });
```

- client side

```
// Assume you have a state variable to keep track of the currently open chat screen
const [currentChatUserId, setCurrentChatUserId] = useState(null);

// Handle the 'send message' event
socket.on('send message', ({ senderId, message }) => {
  if (senderId === currentChatUserId) {
    // Append the message to the DOM of the currently open chat screen
    // You can use your own logic to update the chat messages in the state
    // or trigger a re-fetch of messages for the open chat screen
  } else {
    // Store the message for later use (e.g., in a Redux store or component state)
    // This way, when the user navigates to the chat screen with the senderId,
    // you can retrieve and display the stored messages
  }
});

// Update the currentChatUserId when the user navigates to a different chat screen
const handleChatNavigation = (userId) => {
  setCurrentChatUserId(userId);
  // Fetch messages for the selected chat screen or load stored messages
};
```

Hope to be helpful for your understanding.

Comment: Would it be scalable to store all messages to be loaded later in something like a redux store? Would a better approach be to just load the latest messages from the database after a user eventually selects the other chat screen?

Comment: It is a better approach that just load the latest msgs from the database than load all msgs in redux.

Comment: These answers are helpful for me. I was on similar trouble.

Comment: @BlueSpider Perfect, thank you. So everytime the user selects a new chat, load the latest 10 messages from the database, correct?

Comment: @BlueSpider Is what I said above correct?

Answer (score 0):

I recoded to send you more brief example, with the variable names on your explanation of scenario, namely test1,2,3.

- server side

```
// Assuming user is the sender (e.g., test2) and targetUserId is the id of the user they are chatting with (e.g., test1)
io.to(test1SocketId).emit('send message', { senderId: test2.id, message: msg });
```

- client side

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// Assume you have a state variable to keep track of the currently open chat screen
const ChatComponent = () => {
  const [currentChatUserId, setCurrentChatUserId] = useState(null);
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  // Handle the 'send message' event
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleSendMessage = ({ senderId, message }) => {
      if (senderId === currentChatUserId) {
        // Append the message to the DOM of the currently open chat screen
        // You can use your own logic to update the chat messages in the state
        setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, message]);
      } else {
        // Store the message for later use (e.g., in a Redux store or component state)
        // This way, when the user navigates to the chat screen with the senderId,
        // you can retrieve and display the stored messages
        // You might want to implement your own logic to handle message storage
      }
    };

    // Replace 'socket' with your actual socket instance
    socket.on('send message', handleSendMessage);

    return () => {
      // Clean up the event listener when the component unmounts
      socket.off('send message', handleSendMessage);
    };
  }, [currentChatUserId]);

  // Update the currentChatUserId when the user navigates to a different chat screen
  const handleChatNavigation = (userId) => {
    setCurrentChatUserId(userId);
    // Fetch messages for the selected chat screen or load stored messages
    // You might want to implement your own logic for fetching messages
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Render your chat UI and append messages from the 'messages' state */}
      <h2>Chatting with {currentChatUserId}</h2>
      {/* Your chat messages UI */}
      {messages.map((message, index) => (
        <div key={index}>{message}</div>
      ))}
      {/* Your chat navigation UI */}
      <button onClick={() => handleChatNavigation('test1')}>Chat with test1</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleChatNavigation('test3')}>Chat with test3</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChatComponent;
```

Hope to be more helpful.